# Retrieve IIS log parameter value from HTTP-Request/Response object

Tags: iis, .net-core, httprequest, httpresponse, asp.net-core-2.2

I want to write custom log for my application similar to IIS log using **.net core**.
For below fields I am not able to retrieve information from **HTTP-Request/Response** object.

**Parameter :**

`. Service Name and Instance Number (s-sitename)
. User Name (cs-username)
. Cookie (cs - Cookie)
. Protocol Substatus(sc substatus)
. Win32 Status(sc-win32-status)
. Bytes Sent (sc-bytes )
. Bytes Received (cs-bytes)`

apart from above fields, I have able to extract other fields information. 
Example:  [Server Name, Protocol Version etc]

**Information regarding position of above fields inside  [HTTP-Request/Response] object or .net core code to extract this information is required.**

Comment: What is "HTTP-Request/Response object"? You don't even have the actual class/property names?

Comment: class HttpContext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http)

Comment: You will have to split this to smaller questions, and then each can be answered separately. Some comes from HTTP header (cookie/user name), and some you cannot access at all (win32 status).

Comment: Could you please tell us that you does not find a proper property in httprequest/httpresponse object or parameter value is null? could you please provide some sample code which you tried?