# How to retrieve IIS log parameter value [Parameter name: Bytes Sent (sc-bytes ) & Bytes Received (cs-bytes)] from HttpContext object

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0, iis-logs

I want to write access log for my application similar to IIS access log
(e.g IIS log file Path: "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex190422.log") using .net core.

For below fields I am able to retrieve information from HttpContext object

- URI Stem(cs-uri-stem)
- URI Query(cs-uri-query)
- Method(cs-method)

But I am not able to retrieve information for following fields

- Bytes Sent (sc-bytes )
- Bytes Received (cs-bytes)

Similar question is asked here:
[Retrieve IIS log parameter value from HTTP-Request/Response object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55794873/retrieve-iis-log-parameter-value-from-http-request-response-object)

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.